# Regular expression: determine info from utilite output with grep

Tags: regex, grep

An utilite [nconvert](http://www.xnview.com/en/nconvert/) produce info about some file:

```
nconvert -info file.tiff
```

output

```
** NCONVERT v7.00 (c) 1991-2017 Pierre-E Gougelet (Apr 18 2017/09:49:26) **
        Version for Windows NT/9x/2000/Xp/Vista/7  (All rights reserved)
** This is freeware software (for non-commercial use)

Over...

file.tiff : Success
    Format               : TIFF
    Name                 : tiff
    Compression          : CCITT Group 4
    Width                : 3194
    Height               : 5056
    Components per pixel : 1
    Bits per component   : 1
    Depth                : 1
    # colors             : 2
    Color model          : RGB
    Bytes Per Plane      : 400
    Orientation          : Top Left
    Xdpi                 : 600
    Ydpi                 : 600
    Page(s)              : 30
    Info:
      Photometric Interpretation: White=0
      PhotometricInterpretation: 0
      PlanarConfiguration: 1
      SamplesPerPixel: 1
      Software: LIBFORMAT (c) Pierre-e Gougelet
    Metadata             : ( EXIF )
```

I need extract numeral information using grep. Suppose, I want to define number of pages, I use

```
nconvert -info file.tiff | grep -oP "(?<=Page\(s\)).*$"
```

I get:

```
      : 30
```

**But I need only number `30`!**

Modification below also does not bring the desired result

```
nconvert -info efile.tiff | grep -oP "(?<=Page\(s\)\s+\:).*$"
```

**How can I get info after colons?**

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `grep`:

```
nconvert -info efile.tiff | grep -oP 'Page\(s\)\h*:\h*\K\d+'
30
```

`\K` will reset the matched information.

You can also use `awk`:

```
nconvert -info efile.tiff | awk -F '[: \t]*' '$2=="Page(s)"{print $3}'
30
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the positive lookbehind with `\K` *match reset* operator here to allow variable width pattern before the value you need to extract:

```
grep -oP 'Page\(s\)\s*:\s*\K.*'
```

Here,

- `Page\(s\)` - matches `Page(s)`
- `\s*:\s*`  - matches `:` enclosed with 0+ whitespaces
- `\K` -  omits the text matched so far
- `.*` - matches the rest of the line.

Answer (score 1):

```
nconvert -info file.tiff |
sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*Page\(s\)/{s/^[^[:digit:]]*//;p}'
```

should do it.
__

**Explanation**

- `-n` in `sed` restricts it printing every line to the output. By default it prints everything.
- `/pattern/` is self explanatory, ie to look for a pattern, enclose it in two forward slashes.
- `/^pattern/` looks for a pattern in the beginning of the line
- `/^[[:space:]]*Page\(s\)/` looks for any number of spaces in the beginning of a line followed by `Page(s)`
- If we find the above part in the lines, then `sed` processes the commands which are inside the curly braces `{commands}`.
- The first command is substitute which has the format `s/patten/substitution/`.
- `[]` in regex is used for character ranges, for example `[A-Z]` or `[0-9]`
- But character classes are also available and the `[:digit:]` character class is the same as `0-9` By putting a `^` in the beginning of `[]` you're negating that particular character class. So in short `s/^[^[:digit:]]*//` means delete any non-digit characters at the beginning. Note `*` means any `zero or more` times.
- The `p` at the end prints the lines. Also not `s` and `p` commands are separated by a semicolon

Comment: Can you, please,  explain me a little bit what mean string between `'...'`?

Comment: @Sergio : I have put a bit of explanation :)